# Как исправить наложение текста в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Написал код который выводит количество очков игрока на экран при нажатии ЛКМ, но проблема в том, что очки накладываются друг на друга. Как это исправить?

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 1280))
pygame.display.set_caption('test')

FPS = 20
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def drawW():
    win.blit(walkbg[0], (0, 0))
    win.blit(pygame.image.load('ghost.png'), (-250, 700))

class TextObject:
    def __init__(self, x, y, text_func, color, font_name, font_size):
        self.pos = (230, 100)
        self.text_func = text_func
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(font_name, font_size)
        self.bounds = self.get_surface(text_func())

def run_game():
    drawW()
    pygame.display.update()

    score = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                score += 1

                f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 76)
                txt = ("SCORE: " + " " + str(score))
                text = f1.render(txt, True, (255, 255, 255))
                win.blit(text, (230, 100))
        pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(FPS)
run_game()
```

Вот что выходит в самой игре
[image: ЛКМ нажата около 15 раз]

Comment: А что находится в `walkbg[0]`?

Comment: walkbg - список в котором храниться задний фон

Answer (score 2):

Перенес `drawW` внутри цикла игры, *и немного по мелочи поменял*.

Попробуйте:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 1280))
pygame.display.set_caption('test')

FPS = 20
f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 76)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def drawW():
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # win.blit(walkbg[0], (0, 0))
    # win.blit(pygame.image.load('ghost.png'), (-250, 700))


def run_game():
    score = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                score += 1
                break

        drawW()
        
        txt = f"SCORE: {score}"
        text = f1.render(txt, True, (255, 255, 255))
        win.blit(text, (230, 100))
        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)

run_game()
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @Evir, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)